# C#. Возведение в степень чисел Decimal

Tags: c#, decimal

Необходимо получить число с 20 знаками после запятой. пользуюсь функцией Math.Pow(), но она работает только с double. Существует ли функция, которая возведет e в степень 3.3746289746352617283? Если нет, как можно реализовать? СТЕПЕНЬ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ДРОБНОЙ

Comment: Вроде есть nuget пакет https://stackoverflow.com/a/62051024/8324991 да и другие ответы там посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: Оформлю тогда ответом )

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этом [ответе на английском СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62051024/8324991) рекомендуют скачать `NuGet` пакет `DecimalMath.DecimalEx` и использовать `Pow` из него:

```cs
DecimalEx.Pow(number,power);
```

Там же по ссылке есть и другие рецепты в ответах к вопросу.